# updating mysql database email column with id

Tags: mysql, sql-update, concatenation

I'm trying to update a column used for email in my database with the site id for the same row..
I've tried the following:

```
UPDATE LOCATIONS 
SET email ='se".site_id."@myemail.com' 
WHERE customer='MyCustomer' AND site_id='5555';
```

expecting the email column to be se5555 at myemail.com
but that wasn't the case. Should I use CONCAT?

Comment: yes use concat function

Comment: why was this downvoted?

Comment: Thanks Timgavin, I'm learning and not sure why it was downvoted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `concat` function of mysql like this:

```
 UPDATE LOCATIONS SET email = concat('se',site_id,'@myemail.com') WHERE   
 customer='MyCustomer' AND site_id='5555';
```

Comment: thank you, it worked perfect and I used ROUND as well as the site IDs are in the format XXXX.xx

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely use `concat()`.  I also like to use `replace()` for this type of operation:

```
UPDATE LOCATIONS
    SET email = replace('se<site_id>@myemail.com', '<site_id>', site_id)
    WHERE customer = 'MyCustomer' AND site_id = '5555';
```

This is helpful when you have multiple substitutions -- the first argument is a template so it is easier to see what you are doing and to modify.